# Why would only 50% of my drawables be drawn?

Tags: android, drawable

I have tried to create a simple application that draws a png graphic where the screen is touched. The problem that I have is that only every other instance of the graphic I add is actually rendered. Each time I add a new instance, the pattern alternates. I always get only 50% of the graphics rendered.

I am using android level 3 on HTC Hero.

To explain the problem a little more, this is the draw method I am calling from the surface holder callback:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  drawOK = true;
  drawIcon(100.0f, 100.0f);//line-1
  drawIcon(50.0f, 100.0f);//line-2
  drawIcon(100.0f, 50.0f);//line-3
  drawIcon(50.0f, 50.0f);//line-4
  //drawIcon(200.0f, 200.0f);//line-5
  //drawIcon(100.0f, 200.0f);//line-6
 }
```

When I have lines 5 & 6 commented out (as shown), I only see lines 2 & 4 rendered. When I add in line 5, I see lines 1,3 & 5 rendered. Finally when I add in line 6, I see lines 2,4 & 6 rendered.

Why would this be?

To explain the rest of the application in more detail. I have the following layout xml:

```
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/SurfaceView01" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

I.e. I have a single surface view onto which I will draw the png graphic.

My activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback and intialises like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);

    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}
```

I.e. I chain the call, and set the content view using the R class. I then obtain a reference to the surface view and register the activity as a surface holder callback.

I have a method that draws the icon to the screen. This is it:

```
private void drawIcon(float x, float y) {
  if (!drawOK) return;
  Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
         // getting instance each time in case problem is related to reusing obj
         mFiringImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
         //so i can see overlapping icons, to rule out clipping issues
      mFiringImage.setAlpha(125); 
         // This mutate call is incase the bounds are shared state, which i doubt
      mFiringImage.mutate().setBounds( 
       (int)x-mFiringImage.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 
       (int)y-mFiringImage.getIntrinsicHeight()/2, 
       (int)x+mFiringImage.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 
       (int)y+mFiringImage.getIntrinsicHeight()/2
      );
      mFiringImage.draw(canvas);
      holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
 }
```

I.e. I lock the canvas, obtain the drawable png resource, set the bounds (using mutate just in case), and ask the drawable to draw itself on the canvas. Note I don't ever draw unless the surface has been created.

I really am puzzled here.

All help appreciated.

p.s. Here is the full listing:

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class Toucher extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 private Drawable mFiringImage;
 private SurfaceView surfaceView;
 private boolean drawOK;
 private SurfaceHolder holder;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);

  // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
  holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  float x = event.getX();
  float y = event.getY();
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "=========================");
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Action="+event.getAction());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "History Size="+event.getHistorySize());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Pressure="+event.getPressure());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Raw X="+event.getRawX());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Raw Y="+event.getRawY());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "X="+x);
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Y="+y);
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Precision X="+event.getXPrecision());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Precision Y="+event.getYPrecision());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Size="+event.getSize());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "=========================");

  drawIcon(x, y);

  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

 private void drawIcon(float x, float y) {
  if (!drawOK) return;
  Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
  mFiringImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
  mFiringImage.setAlpha(125);
  mFiringImage.mutate().setBounds(
    (int)x-mFiringImage.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 
    (int)y-mFiringImage.getIntrinsicHeight()/2, 
    (int)x+mFiringImage.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 
    (int)y+mFiringImage.getIntrinsicHeight()/2
  );
  mFiringImage.draw(canvas);
  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
   int height) {
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  drawOK = true;
  drawIcon(100.0f, 100.0f);//1
  drawIcon(50.0f, 100.0f);//2
  drawIcon(100.0f, 50.0f);//3
  drawIcon(50.0f, 50.0f);//4
  //drawIcon(200.0f, 200.0f);//5
  //drawIcon(100.0f, 200.0f);//6
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if (!hasFocus) drawOK = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that there are two canvases? One that I have locked. The other being rendered to the screen?

In that case what are the best practices for ensuring things are drawn on both canvases?

Comment: The android documentation says this. I think I took it too literally :0):

Note: On each pass you retrieve the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder, the previous state of the Canvas will be retained. In order to properly animate your graphics, you must re-paint the entire surface. For example, you can clear the previous state of the Canvas by filling in a color with drawColor() or setting a background image with drawBitmap(). Otherwise, you will see traces of the drawings you previously performed.

Comment: Please try to indent your code properly, there is a button at the top of the editor with "110110" on it, you just have to select the piece of code and click it. Otherwise, you writting is crazy to read.

Comment: Apologies. I had noscript running and could not see those buttons. I was wondering how to get it formatted properly. Does it require spaces instead of tabs? That's not how I write code :0(